# git: 'submit' is not a git command error when trying to submit

Tags: git, clion

I'm trying to submit an assignment in Clion with Git. After 'commit' I'm typing 'git submit' in the console, but I'm getting the following error:

```
git: 'submit' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
```

It never happened to me before, what could be the problem?

Thank you

Comment: what is `git submit` supposed to do? It seems likely to be an alias you've come to rely on. It would be wise to review the documentation for the tool you're using here (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/commit-and-push-changes.html).

Answer (score 1):

Because `git submit` is not a command, do you mean `git push` ?

Answer (score 1):

`submit` is not a git command. Possible commands would be:
`git commit -m "aliasForSubmit?"` or `git push`.